# Show errors received by Laravel in async actions Redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, react-redux, redux-toolkit

This is the `async thunk` function in my slice, I'm using `axios` (http is coming from another file defined as axios.create())

```
export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk("auth/fetchUsers", async (data) => {
  const response = await http.post("/login", data);
  return response.data;
});
```

In above `data` is an object passed through dispatch method (data contains email and password).

This is my initial state,

```
const initialState = {
    loading: false,
    user: [],
    error: [],
  },
```

This is my reducer, I use extra reducers So I can stage the above `loginUser` into stages as `pending,fullfilled,rejected`

```
const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(loginUser.pending, (state) => {
      state.apiHandler.loading = true;
    });
    builder.addCase(loginUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.apiHandler.loading = false;
      state.apiHandler.user = action.payload;
      state.apiHandler.error = [];
    });
    builder.addCase(loginUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.apiHandler.loading = false;
      state.apiHandler.user = [];
      state.apiHandler.error = action.error.message;
    });
  },
});
```

I'm trying to get the exact error messages returning from Laravel. But I'm getting the message as `Request failed with status code 422` in the `rejected` cycle.With postman I'm retrieving the exact error,

```
{
    "message": "Incorrect Credentials"
}
```

This is a potion of my Laravel code, (So if something is not fullfilled it should return errors),

```
$request->validate([
  'email'    => 'required | exists:users',
  'password' => 'required'
]);
```

**My question is**: How to retrieve the exact error messages with `asyncThunk` reject method without retrieving `Request failed with status code 422` as the error.

Comment: Depends on your `http.post` implementation. Does it throw an error on error status code responses? Is the error message placed at `error.message` as your reducer implements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attached `try catch` and passed the 2nd argument as `{rejectWithValue}` for the `createAsyncThunk`, and catching the errors with `action.payload` in  `case.rejected` ,

```
export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/fetchUsers",
  async (payload, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await http.post("/login", payload);
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
);

extraReducers: (builder) => {
   ...
    builder.addCase(loginUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.user = [];
      state.error = action.payload;
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about your project structure. However, you can actually get the Laravel errors, by waiting for a json response and accessing response's `.errors` .

For Example:

```
if (response. Status === 422) {
    const validation = await response.json();
    this.message= validation.errors
    this.error= true;
}
```

According to your project structure, place this logic in your responses, anywhere suitable.

What I see here is you return response.data anyways, while laravel errors reside in response.errors object.

I hope it helps.